# Не отправляется Контакт Форм 7

Tags: wordpress

Помогите найти ошибку почему не отправляются все формы на сайте http://electric.spstroy.ru до передачи сайта клиенту все работало. клиент утверждает что ничего не изменял. вывод console.log(event.detail); на скрине. можно как-нибудь получить более развернутую инфу, а не просто status: "mail_failed"
[image: скрин]

Comment: Покажите скрипт который обрабатывает вашу форму после отправки

Comment: То, что работает на одном сервере, может не работать на другом.

Comment: Из вашего вопроса ничего непонятно. Это один и тот же сервер, или вы перенесли сайт на другой для передачи заказчику. Это shared хостинг или VPS? Как отправляется почта - средствами сервера, или с помощью ПЛАГИНА типа WP Mail SMTP? Какие настройки отправки (адрес отправителя)? Домен с адресом отправителя имеет SPF, DKIM, DMARC?

Comment: Ошибки в конструкторе форм есть?

Comment: ошибок в конструкторе форм нет

Comment: сервер один https://server62.hosting.reg.ru, переноса не было, почта отправляется плагином WPCF7. адрес отправителя <wordpress@electric.spstroy.ru> никаких настроек SPF, DKIM, DMARC я не делал.

Comment: также на событиях отправки форм висят обработчики для Яндекс-целей. проблема не в них - когда я закомментировал этот код ничего не изменилось